# File is auto created, the script should auto rename and move it, but they don't move

Tags: powershell-2.0

long time listener, first time caller,

I have a need to create a Powershell script (ver 2 or lower) that:

-continually monitors one specific directory for new/changed files
-logs the file that was created with a date/time stamp in a log file that's:
--created on a daily basis with the name of "log Date/Time.txt"
-renames the file, appending the date/time
-logs that it renamed it
-maps a drive with a specific username/password combo
-moves it from dirA to dirB (the mapped drive is dirB)
-logs that it moved it
-unmaps the drive
-if for whatever reason it stopped running and we start it back up, it'll rename, maps the drive, move, unmap the drive, and log all files in dirA to dirB

In it's current form, I've stripped the Mapping of the dir out to troubleshoot it moving the file on a local drive just to keep from troubleshooting a network drive.

I've been staring at this for over a week and am tired of hitting my head against the desk. Can someone PLEASE put me out of my misery and let me know what I've done wrong?

THANK YOU in advance!

I've honestly tried SO many combos, different routines, I don't even know what to put here.

In the box below, I've put the main part of the script that isn't working correctly It renames the files as they come in, but doesn't move them.

```
$rename = $_.Name.Split(".")[0] + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date -Format MM.dd.yyy) + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date  -Format hh.mm.ss) + ".log"

Write-Output "File: '$name' exists at: $source - renaming existing file first" >> $scriptlog

Rename-Item $_ -NewName $rename

Wait-Event -Timeout 3

Move-Item "$_($_.Directory)$name" -destination $destination

Write-Output "File: '$name' moved to $destination on $date" >> $scriptlog
```

Whole code available below:

```
#Log Rename/Move script
$userName = "copyuser"
$newpass = Read-Host -Prompt 'Type the new Password'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $newpass -AsPlainText -Force

$PathToMonitor = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FolderA"
$destination = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\FolderB"
$scriptlog = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ScriptLogs\" + [datetime]::Today.ToString('MM-dd-yyy') + "_TransferLog.txt"

$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path  = $PathToMonitor
$FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$dateTime = [datetime]::Today.ToString('MM-dd-yyy') + " " + [datetime]::Now.ToString('HH:mm:ss')
Write-Output "*******************************************************************************************" >> $scriptLog
Write-Output "*********************Starting Log Move Script $dateTime**********************" >> $scriptLog
Write-Output "*******************************************************************************************" >> $scriptLog

$Action = {
$details = $event.SourceEventArgs
$Name = $details.Name
$FullPath = $details.FullPath
$OldFullPath = $details.OldFullPath
$OldName = $details.OldName
$ChangeType = $details.ChangeType
$Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
$text = "{0} was {1} at {2}" -f $FullPath, $ChangeType, $Timestamp
Write-Output "" >> $scriptlog
Write-Output $text >> $scriptlog


switch ($ChangeType)
{
    'Changed' { "CHANGE"
        Get-ChildItem -path $FullPath -Include *.log | % {
            $rename = $_.Name.Split(".")[0] + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date -Format MM.dd.yyy) + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date  -Format hh.mm.ss) + ".log"
            Write-Output "File: '$name' exists at: $source - renaming existing file first" >> $scriptlog
            Rename-Item $_ -NewName $rename
            Wait-Event -Timeout 3
            Move-Item "$_($_.Directory)$name" -destination $destination
            Write-Output "File: '$name' moved to $destination on $date" >> $scriptlog
        }
    }    
    'Created' { "CREATED"
        Get-ChildItem -path $FullPath -Include *.log | % {
            $rename = $_.Name.Split(".")[0] + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date -Format MM.dd.yyy) + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date  -Format hh.mm.ss) + ".log"
            Write-Output "File: '$name' exists at: $source - renaming existing file first" >> $scriptlog
            Rename-Item $_ -NewName $rename
            Wait-Event -Timeout 3
            Move-Item "$($_.Directory)$rename" -Destination $destination
            Write-Output "File: '$name' moved to $destination on $date" >> $scriptlog
        }
    }
    'Deleted' { "DELETED"
    }
    'Renamed' { 
    }
    default { Write-Output $_ >> $scriptlog}
}
}

$handlers = . {
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Changed -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSChange
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Created -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
}

Write-Output "Watching for changes to $PathToMonitor" >> $scriptlog

try
{
do
{
    Wait-Event -Timeout 1
    Write-host "." -NoNewline

} while ($true)
}
finally
{
# EndScript
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSChange
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSCreate
$handlers | Remove-Job
$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
$FileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
write-output "Event Handler disabled." >> $scriptlog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found my issue. A dumb issue if I look at it and think about it. It was how I was calling the current directory containing the file(s) to move after being renamed.

```
Move-Item "$_($_.Directory)$name" -destination $destination
```

The issue in the above code is the "$*($*.Directory). It needs to be:

```
Move-Item -path $PathToMonitor$name -destination $destination
```

Other things may work, and may be better, but at least that fixes the moving after naming issue I was having.

Now onto adding the Mapping Drive and other stuff that's needed to fully finish what I need.

If I think about it, I'll post my entire code when done for anyone else it can help in the future.